# npm installation error angular 2

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I am getting this error while installing Angular2

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5

npm ERR! Cannot read property 'path' of null
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\angular2-demo\npm-debug.log
```

How to solve this

Comment: do have the latest node installed in your system

Comment: @RahulSingh it looks like `npm  v4.0.5` and `node v7.4.0`

Comment: but angular to work i guess u need version 6 or 7 above

Comment: Can you run it with the `--verbose` flag?

Comment: verbose flag means

Comment: The `--verbose` flag will output more information when you try to install the package. Using that information may help us determine a solution.

Comment: @RahulSingh, node v4.x.x or higher and npm 3.x.x or higher are the versions required for angular 2 , i think it is not error for versions

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/npm-packages.html

Comment: @udaya, are you using any proxy ?

Comment: @Naga Sai A yes but running as administrator

Comment: Can you try setting up proxy by          npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080

Comment: do you have angular latest version installed ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some standard instructions and rules to follow in such scenarios:

> 1-Check your system has npm and node installed & are they of latest versions (most probably).

**Install nodejs if not available:**

> Download the Windows installer from the [Nodes.js® web site.](http://nodejs.org/)
>
> Run the installer (the .msi file you downloaded in the previous step.)
>
> Follow the prompts in the installer (Accept the license agreement, click the NEXT button a bunch of times and accept the default installation settings).
>   installer
>
> Restart your computer. You won’t be able to run Node.js® until you restart your computer.
>
> Restart your computer. You won’t be able to run Node.js® until you restart your computer.

Now check `node -v`

For further setup and checup [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows)